# I'm trying to clear all the Ghidra instances in my machine before reinstalling it and I'm seeing some anomalies

Tags: ghidra

I downloaded 3 different instances of Ghidra without realizing, and after I did the `locate Ghidra` command, it returned:

[image]

The second folder `ghidra_scripts` is unimportant and doesn't contain any instances in it,
but the `.ghidra` folder had 2 instances in it and I went inside it and removed both 9.1 and 9.2 instances from it already and did the `locate ghidra` command again, and it was still there for some reason, so I tried to 'rm' it and it returned no such file or directory under this directory

I restarted my computer to see if it would still be there, and it is.

I also see a ghidra.rb file under `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/ghidra.rb`

I already did the `brew uninstall Ghidra` command and it returned

[image: 'Cask "Ghidra" is not installed]

Should I remove this file under Casks before I continue towards redownloading Ghidra again?

Comment: Try SuperUser for package management/installation issues. Just because it involves Ghidra doesn’t make your problem to be about RE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely remove these directories. These directories are created by default in your home directory (`System.getProperty("user.home")`). These directories contain preferences, script/application logs and other “cached” files. (This cache path is decided using [getUserSettingsDirectory()](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/framework/Application.html#getUserSettingsDirectory())) divided by you Ghidra version.

Also, if you reinstall, rerun Ghidra, they get recreated.